# Cannot get SecKeyRef from .der file was MD5 signature

Tags: objective-c, md5, public-key, der

I am trying to get SecKeyRef from a given .der file, I have researched and found some useful code, but SecCertificateCreateWithData method always return nil, and I guess that the root cause is the .der file was MD5 signature, because I have tried to create a new key using openssl without MD5 or SHA signature then I could import the key into KeyChain and get SecKeyRef successfully.

So anyone has experience on this please help me how to solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone know this please help me.

Comment: I have tried to use openssl to create a new key but did not sign it then I could get SecKeyRef successfully, so I think the cause is the key file was signed.

Comment: It seems not many people have faced this problem :(

Comment: Solved my own question by reading the key from PEM file, remove post-fix and pre-fix (like this:----- PUBLIC KEY ------), strip public key header then I can import it into the key chain.